# Can you customise the way a class is displayed in a GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview, attributes

I am trying to easily visualise data in a `GridView` using the `DataSource` property. This works well for atomic data types, but for custom classes, C# doesn't know how to display them. How can you tell it how to display the item in a customised way?

The following code:

```
[DisplayName("Person")]
public class Person
{
    public Person(string first, string last)
    {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[DisplayName("Some contract")]
public class Contract
{
    public Contract(Person employer, Person employee, int salary)
    {
        Employer = employer;
        Employee = employee;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public Person Employer {get; set;}
    public Person Employee { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

class MyGridView : GridView
{

    public MyGridView() 
    {
        Person[] people = { new Person("John", "Smith"), new Person("Adam", "Bell"), new Person("Kate", "Regan") };
        Contract[] contracts = { new Contract(people[0], people[1], 10000), new Contract(people[0], people[2], 30000) };
        this.DataSource = contracts;
    }
}
```

Produces this:

[image]

Ideally, where now it says `GridReportForm+Person`, I'd like it to say "John Smith", "Adam Bell" etcetera. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just override `Object.ToString()` and return a string suitable for display.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Comment: +1 Been down this road before and I think this is the only way. It's sloppy if your class isn't an explicit view model because you're modifying such a low-level, core method to one specific purpose.

Comment: @Yuck Yes, unfortunately the context of `ToString()` is not well-defined.  One *could* wrap the `Person` object in a special "view" object that overrides `ToString()` just for the grid view... that's probably the best possible compromise in this scenario.